# S/R & C/S calls in Autosar

Tags: autosar

In Autosar Application Can we have both kind of Interfaces Like Sender/receiver Interfaces and Client/Server Interfaces?

Or is there only S/R interface between 2 Application components at application level in autosar architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can arbitrarily mix PortPrototypes typed by different PortInterfaces (e.g. ClientServerInterface, SenderReceiverInterface) in any SwComponentType.